# Encryption -- how to do it

Tags: python, encryption, tkinter

**issue**

I am writing an application in python. It takes care of contacts and other information about a person. I want to prompt the user for a master key every time that he/she wants to perform a major operation. I have everything figured out. The whole application is ready and works well. But I store the master key in a file. This file is easily readable in the plain text form. And my friends who tried using this said that the software is useless if I don't apply a strong encryption algorithm as users would simply trust the application with the details that can be easily stolen.

**goal**

To store the master key in a form that can be deciphered (or read) only by my program.

**other things**

1. there is an option for the user to change the master key.
2. The master key will be read and deciphered only once. At the start of the program. It will be stored in a variable then and and used from this variable.
3. It is a GUI application. And I am using python Tkinter.

**details**

Please note that the data is stored using another encryption that is not un breakable but enough for this kind of information.

I have not used any database to store the information.

The only data to be encrypted is a master key. It is an alphanumeric string of length anywhere from 7 to 80 characters.

**specs**

```
1. Python 2.7
2. Tkinter 8.5
3. Linux Mint 14
```

Comment: Given your issue, why not cipher the data using a _master key_ ? This way you don't have to store the key and your data should be secure. Note also that you should try to limit the possibilities of the attacker to exploit the shape of the data (and not the properties of the cryptosystem itself)

Comment: Could you provide more information about the data that could be ciphered ? (length, nature, formatting ...) Do you have some requirements such as random access needed in the file ?

Comment: How do you store your contacts? Is it a database and if so, which one (sqlite, postgres,...)?

Comment: Could you be more specific on the user data encryption scheme ?

Comment: Please do not invent your own schemes, your knowledge about cryptography seems minimal at best. Check how popular open source password storage applications work instead. Before programming, when you are contemplating a solution, use security.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The user picks the master key, and you encrypt it and save the encryption to the file.
2. When the user wants to do a major operation, you prompt for their master key, and you encrypt what they enter.
3. Compare #2 to #1 and if they match you let the user proceed.  Otherwise, you tell the user to get lost.

> To store the master key in a form that can be deciphered

Nope.  If you can decipher it, hackers can decipher it.  You want something that is impossible to decipher by a super computer working non-stop for 100 years.  Depending on how sensitive the data is, SHA-1/SHA-2/SHA-3 may be all you need.  See here: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)

Note that if anyone steals a copy of the file containing the encryptions, and they enter one of the encryptions when your app prompts them for their master key, your app will encrypt the encryption, and the result won't match any of the encryptions in the file.

Comment: okay.. thanks a lot! i read the algorithm and the pseudo code on wikipedia.. but do i have to write the corresponding code to encrypt and to de-encrypt myself? or is there another way?

Comment: and can i do it the other way round? can i
1. take the master key from the user
2. encrypt it and store it
3. and when the application is reopened i can de-encrypt it.

why i wanna do this is because then i would not have to encrypt whatever the user had entered each time user enters it.

Comment: @IcyFlame One of the purposes of hash functions is _one-wayness_, thus no, there's no way back. You cannot find the original string given the hash digest in a reasonable computation time.

Comment: Sorry for asking that. I forgot to use google before asking. I found hashlib in python. Thanks a lot for this amazing answer. And as for doing it the other way around, i found on wiki that this is the correct way to do it. And your comment just clarified it all. And moreover, if i cannot find the original string from here, I should not use this has algorithm for storing the contact details itself right? then what should i use for them? I have a self developed algorithm that is very simple to break and even people who solve the deciphering puzzles in the newspaper can spot the pattern easily!

Comment: Can you tell me a way to encrypt the data so that i can decipher it back to what it was and present it to the user once the user has authorized himself/herself?

Comment: Just recommending a secure hash when encryption is required won't help to solve the question...

Comment: > 1. take the master key from the user 2. encrypt it and store it 3. and when the application is reopened i can de-encrypt it. why i wanna do this is because then i would not have to encrypt whatever the user had entered each time user enters it.<  How could it possibly matter to you whether you:1) encrypt what's entered and compare to your list or 2)retrieve from list, decrypt, then compare to what was entered?  The whole idea with encryption is that you can never decrypt.  Mathematicians work very hard to figure out algorithms that can't be decrypted so that we can secure our data.

Comment: @7stud thanks!! i did not understand the concept when i posted that.... a little helped me understand the concept!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need, or even want, complex encryption for passwords--and what you are describing is a password, not a key (it just grants access, it doesn't encrypt the data). Current best practice is to store passwords salted and hashed.  That is, when the user creates a new account and enters a password, you build a string from the password plus user name plus a "salt" (which is just a small string that's the same for everyone on your site--this is to thwart rainbow table attacks). Then you run that string through a good hash algorithm--something like SHA1 is fine (even MD5 is more than adequate, despite reports to the contrary). You certainly don't need anything like AES.  Anyway, now that you have a hash, you store the hash in the database, and not the password. Even a strong cipher like AES is useless if don't do the rest right.

Next time the user logs in, you do the same: add his password to user name and salt, hash that, and compare the hash to what's stored. There's no way, even in principle, for you to know what his password was, so no way for an attacker to find it even if they get your database and know your algorithm and salt.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to secure your sensitive data by a password, you will be better off with an "off-the-shelf" symmetric encryption algorithm like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). This way, your data will be strongly encrypted (assumed you get a few parameter right) and you wouldn't even need to store your password somewhere on disk.

[PyCrypto](http://www.pycrypto.org/) is a widely used toolkit for cryptography and offers AES as well. It can be a little cumbersome to understand the necessary details to get started, especially because all examples I could find about "How to use PyCrypto to do AES?" were all a little bit different (e.g. initialization of the algorithm, padding).

For starters, [this blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/06/25/aes-encryption-of-files-in-python-with-pycrypto/) will give you some explanation and code snippets to begin with. (Note: The code presented there writes the decrypted (=actual) data to a file, which might be a severe risk. After you understand how the code works, you might modify the code in order to store the decrypted data as a string and read the contents from it with the application code you already have.)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by your question in comments. Here is a pattern slightly different than the one you are currently building.

First of all, if you cipher something, do it using well recognized and publicly known tools. The nowadays classic is AES. This is the raw cipher and performs encryption on 16-bytes blocks. All it needs is a *secret key* which can be of 128, 192 or 256 bit lengths.
*Actually, the underlying cipher supports more lengths than that but the algorithm has been heavily tested on these 3 lengths so you might stick with them.*

Now, you have to determine **how** you can use the cipher in your particular case. The choice of the **encryption mode** is very important. An **encryption mode** is a particular way to use a given cipher. The most basic is *ECB* (electronic code book). It simply consists of applying the cipher block after block with a given key. You should avoid it like the plague !

When you have the **encryption mode**, you are still not done. You must then find what we can call the **key schedule**. That is to say given a unique key such as a password or passphrase, you must derive the required cryptographic keys to supply to the underlying cryptosystem (the block cipher + the encryption mode).

I will begin with a simple pattern that is based on AES-128 (AES used with 128 bits key).

### The key schedule

A good way to derive keys from a passphrase is to use hash functions. You only have to hash the passphrase and (optional) additional data to get a practical key. Here is what I suggest, based on [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) construction :

**Input :** A password *K* of 7 to 80 characters, a string *s* that specifies the targeted user (like a pseudo) and hash function *H*.

**Output :** A cryptographic key *K<sub>s</sub>*

You derive *K<sub>s</sub>* using the following process

> *K<sub>s</sub>* = *HMAC-H*( *s*, *K* )

Depending on the digest length of *H*, you might have to truncate it to get only 128 bits. (Well known hash functions usually have an output with more than 128 bits). You can use *H* = SHA-1 or *H* = MD5 for example.

### The cryptosystem

I don't know how long can be the data you store but I assume it is not too large. I suggest *CBC* (Cipher Block Chaining) mode. This mode requires the famous 128 bit key and an extra 128 bit vector called the *Initialization Vector* (**IV** in short). You must *NEVER* use the same (key, IV) pair twice ! (rule [1])

Now, here is what you could do, assuming :

- You have one file of data per user
- You accept a little overhead on your IO operations

You will cipher the data on a 512 bytes basis (that is 32 blocks of 16 bytes). The **IV** pattern will be simple : you start by encoding 0 on 16 bytes and you *increment* it each time a new 512 bytes block is appended.

A quick example :

User Cthulhu wants to stay in touch with his friends to share his evil plots. His passphrase is doom.

- His data file will be ciphered using *K<sub>Cthulhu</sub>*, with *K* = doom, thus *K<sub>Cthulhu</sub>* = *HMAC-H*(Cthulhu, doom)
- The file is divided into chunks of 512 bytes. The **IV** for data chunk number *i* is the common integer binary representation of *i* on 16 bytes.

I know that Cthulhu can have many many evil friends, but I can reasonably assume that the 16 bytes integer won't overflow, therefore rule [1] is enforced.

Here, you should have a basic cryptosystem which is not so bad but still can be improved :

- Using [authenticated encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) with a **MAC** (message authentication code) scheme. *Note that some execution modes include this, such as [CCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode)*
- Strengthening the **key schedule** : there might be rainbow tables attacks for the hash function you chose. To make things complicated for an attacker, introduce a [random salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) in the process.
- Changing the pattern *"a file per user"* since it still leaks some information such as "hey, what you will find here is related to the same user".

The first is quite easily introduced (juste use **CCM** instead of **CBC** and you're almost done). However, the last point is much more difficult to solve. The things you would have to do can be similar to the things made in a *filesystem*.

Answer (score 1):

> do i have to write the corresponding code to encrypt and to 
>   de-encrypt myself? or is there another way?

As mentioned, hashlib is a standard python module, and your system should also come with some kind of encryption program.  On my system it's called openssl, and you can specify many different encryption algorithms.

```
#python 3
import subprocess as sp

master_key = b'hello world'
my_subprocess = sp.Popen(['openssl', 'sha1'], stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE);


my_subprocess.stdin.write(master_key)
my_subprocess.stdin.close()
print(my_subprocess.stdout.read().rstrip())
```

Comment: this may sound silly. but what does the `b` in `b'hello world'` mean?